# How to disable stack canaries for specific functions?

Tags: c, gcc

With `gcc`, is it possible to compile with `-fstack-protector`, but omit for a specific function.

For example, say i have two functions.

```c
void a() {
  ...
}

void b() {
  ...
}
```

Can I tell the compiler to compile a program that will use a canary before the saved return address of `a`, but no canary for `b`?

Comment: I am very curious to know why such a feature would exist.

Comment: Why would you want such a feature?    Do you plan to have buggy functions?

Comment: I was given a challenge for a class. It is an introduction to stack canaries. We are not given the binary but are given the source, and we remote into a machine (netcat or similar) to execute the binary. I observed that there is a single function in the remote binary that does not have a canary before the saved return address. So, I want to compile locally and test some things.

Comment: This seems relevant:  [**6.62.16 Function Specific Option Pragmas**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas).  It certainly seems to me that those options might be able to enable or disable something like stack canaries for specific functions, but I don't have the time right now to formulate an actual answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, I don't _plan_ to...

Comment: @Cheatah There might be a limited supply of canaries.

Comment: `-fstack-protector` doesn't add canaries for all functions; it only adds code to functions it decides heuristically are at risk. (See [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.3.0/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-fstack-protector).) There are several options, which use different heuristics (including `-fstack-protector-explicit`, which requires you to mark the functions you wanted protected), as well as the parameter `ssp-buffer-size`, which lets you tweak the heuristic. I don't know if any of that applies, but it might.

Comment: A possibly simpler way is to put the two functions in different `.c` files (e.g. function `a` in `a.c` and function `b` in `b.c`. Then, change the build so that `a.c` is compiled _with_ `-fstack-protector` and `b.c` is compiled _without_ it. That's what I _would_ have done [and _might_ still do] if Paul hadn't found the correct `__attribute__`. It allows the build to add the option during development/debug and then turn it off for a production build. To me, that's cleaner and easier to maintain

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes, I agree, and that was my original idea in fact, until I tracked down that attribute.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to test if it works (inspect the generated code at Godbolt) but it looks like you can do, for example:

`__attribute__ ((no_stack_protector)) void foo () { ... }`

`no_sanitize` looks like an intriguing option, I wonder who uses that.

Comment: I am aware of this. I should have mentioned that I am using gcc 7.5.0 (specifically Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04). It was not implemented until version 10 (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94722)). However, this led me to the right answer: `__attribute__ ((__optimize__ ("-fno-stack-protector")))`.

Comment: Excellent, we got there in the end.

Comment: *"no_sanitize looks like an intriguing option, I wonder who uses that."* I do. It disables instrumentations from the Address Sanitizer etc. There are some situations where ASan doesn't work properly, e.g. by leaving poison markers in the parent process between clone/exec (clone with `CLONE_VM` set).